# How to create a duplicate copy of SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I need to create similar report with little change. My existing report has a main report with few sub reports attached to it. What I tried so far is;
1) Browsed the project location and find the report with extension .rdl
2) Created a copy of this file by just copy and paste.
3) Renamed the file
But I can see the difference in files as attached below; existing files shows me little blue thing as shows in my screen shot below but the report I got copied is not showing that. So I need to understand why its happening and basically what it does mean to me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9vcH.jpg)
Thank you so much for your help
Thanks!

Comment: what are you using to create your reports? Report builder or visual studio? when you say you browse the project location.. do you do this within VS or using windows explorer?

Comment: Thank you Harry, I am using visual studio. I would appreciate if you can help with this.

Comment: it just looks like an indicator on the file that it has been synched, is the file under source control or in a onedrive folder?